Compass and Straightedge
This is part 75 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
You’re going to need a compass and straightedge for this one. After filling the crossword, connect every pair of I’s appearing in the same column with a vertical line, and draw a circle around every O.
Today I have stayed at a lovely seaside city. I have seen a centuries-old fortress, visited the ruins of an even older church, and taken a dive trip to see the aquatic life of the nearby coral reefs. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Characteristics
6. Word in a green and white sign, often
8. The Beagle, for example
10. Even number whose square root is prime
11. Moves along with the current
12. Fall off the wagon, perhaps
14. Superfood seed
16. Immeasurable
19. Pair on a windshield
21. Peel
24. Its existence is denied by Master Yoda
25. Light
26. Psyche's lover
28. Neighbour of the lira and the rupee
29. Only player ever to score more than Kobe's 81 points in a single game
30. Instances of overabundance
Down
1. Base
2. Boundary
3. Like Inglourious Basterds but unlike Reservoir Dogs
4. Second letter of 26 across, natively
5. Calc documents, say
7. POTUS on the SCOTUS
9. Algerian port
13. Backside, in military lingo
15. Shade
17. Many a beachgoer's goal
18. Tree whose varieties include "Fraser" and "Douglas"
20. "Dang it!"
22. Verb whose meaning is dirtier in the Bible than in Playboy
23. British cars
27. One of 32 in an Oxford v. Cambridge race

Gladys will return in In Open Air.

Solution to the crossword:

 

Clues:

 Across
 1. Characteristics - HALLMARKS
 6. Word in a green and white sign, often - EXIT
 8. The Beagle, for example - SHIP
 10. Even number whose square root is prime - FOUR
 11. Moves along with the current - DRIFTS
 12. Fall off the wagon, perhaps - USE
 14. Superfood seed - CHIA
 16. Immeasurable - UNTOLD
 19. Pair on a windshield - WIPERS
 21. Peel - RIND
 24. Its existence is denied by Master Yoda - TRY
 25. Light - IGNITE
 26. Psyche's lover - EROS
 28. Neighbour of the lira and the rupee - RIAL
 29. Only player ever to score more than Kobe's 81 points in a single game - WILT
 30. Instances of overabundance - SURPLUSES

Down
 1. Base - HEADQUARTERS
 2. Boundary - LIMIT
 3. Like Inglourious Basterds but unlike Reservoir Dogs - MULTILINGUAL
 4. Second letter of 26 across, natively - RHO
 5. Calc documents, say - SPREADSHEETS
 7. POTUS on the SCOTUS - TAFT
 9. Algerian port - ORAN
 13. Backside, in military lingo - SIX
 15. Shade - HUE
 17. Many a beachgoer's goal - TAN
 18. Tree whose varieties include "Fraser" and "Douglas" - FIR
 20. "Dang it!" - RATS
 22. Verb whose meaning is dirtier in the Bible than in Playboy - KNOW
 23. British cars - MINIS
 27. One of 32 in an Oxford v. Cambridge race - OAR

Now, let's do as we're told:

 

You should be able to see that Gladys is in

 ɑqɑbɑ!


sniped!  Was just ready to answer.
